# removeFromParent after SKAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to remove my shootA `SKSpriteNode` after the `SKAction` has been present, but if I do that it seem to trigger before the action.

How can I remove it after it has been presented one time?

This is my code:

```
SKTexture* shootTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"shoot-b"];
shootTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKTexture* shootTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"shoot-a"];
shootTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKAction* flap = [SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[shootTexture1, shootTexture2, ] timePerFrame:0.1] count:1];

SKSpriteNode *shootA = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:shootTexture1];
[shootA setScale:1.0];
shootA.position = CGPointMake(dragon.position.x+40, dragon.position.y-10);
shootA.size = CGSizeMake(shootA.size.width/8, shootA.size.height/8);

[shootA runAction:flap withKey:@"shootGo"];

[self addChild: shootA];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your SKAction to a sequence and then add the `removeFromParent` to the end -

```
SKAction* flap = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                     [SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[shootTexture1, shootTexture2, ] timePerFrame:0.1] count:1],
                                     [SKAction removeFromParent]
                                     ]];
```